# "Да", "ну", "эм" и др. в прямой речи

Tags: пунктуация

Давно интересовал вопрос. Нужно ли отделять запятыми всевозможные междометия в речи персонажей. Например, если они подбирая слова, начинают речь с "нууу" и т.п., например "ну, не знаю"

И вторая часть вопроса - нужна ли в прямой речи запятая после "да" в случае если это 1) ответ на заданный вопрос "да, конечно" и 2) в случае если "да" не означает согласия, например "да ладно"

Answer (score 3):

У вас вопрос - о разнице в пунктуации при междометиях и частицах.
Общее правило - частицы (и союзы) запятыми не выделяются, междометия - выделяются.
Есть некоторые оговорки, я пока опускаю.

Так вот, "ну" может быть междометием или (редко) усилительной частицей.
Поэтому обычно "ну" требует запятых. Но при употреблении для интонационного усиления "ну" уже выполняет роль частицы:

XI. Запятые при междометии

§ 157. Запятыми отделяются междометия эй, ах, о, ох, эх, ну и т. п. (о знаке восклицательном при междометиях см. § 183), например:

...
Нy, коли так, давай скорей чаю да позови дочерей.
Пушкин
...

Примечание. Не являются междометиями и, cледовательно, не отделяются запятыми частицы: о, употребляемая при oбращении, ну, ах, ох и т. п., употребляемые для выражения усилительного оттенка, например:

Ну что ж, Онегин? Ты зеваешь?
Пушкин
...
Ну и денек выдался!
...
http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/?rub=zap&text=19_36

В вашем случае нормально с запятой, но если по контексту понятно, что говорящий использует как усилительную частицу (об этом наверняка знает только автор), то запятая не требуется.

Аналогично и со вторым вопросом:

~1) здесь это утвердительная частица, по функции - то же междометие (сравните "Ага", которое грамматисты причисляют к междометиям), запятая нужна.
~2) здесь это частица усилительная,  запятая не требуется.